# Boy sent to a mental asylum for teenagers where he falls in love

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama

I watched one movie when I was a boy, around 18 years ago maybe and I did not know the name nor the name of any actor, even worse it is not a popular movie. I am asking here because years of googling have not worked :). Hope this is the right place.

Here is all the info I recall from the movie:

**Movie info:**

Drama, Low budget, I saw it on Cinemax. Has some mature content (one boy stabs another). Color.

**What the movie is about**

It is about a normal teenager who is sent to a mental asylum, or some kind of camp for teenagers with mental conditions (can't remember why). In the asylum there is one of his childhood's friends who is obviously mad (aggressive type), a bully and a girl (I think redhead with freckles) with whom the main character falls in love.

The movie is about his struggle in this place, where he clearly doesn't belong. His relief being the girl who he eventually sleeps with and the movie unfolds when the bully after harassing so much the main character ignites the rage of the main character's friend: He stabs the bully and runs away in a car.

The movie finishes with a touching farewell of the two friends (the crazy one is arrested) and a much more mature main character, whose parents come to pick up and apologize.

**Main actor:**

A fat teenager, with Hispanic features. I think I saw him in movies of [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091445/) kind but not as main actor.

**Some tips:**

The movie had some dialogs/situations that stayed in my mind for so long like:

- The crazy aggressive friend tells him that he is nuts because he set his mother's curtains on fire; the main character replies "but you set your mother on fire"
- The girl doesn't read the love notes she gets and instead uses them as hair-clips
- When the parents come to pick him up he's laying outside in the floor and he says he is "creating a tornado"

That's *all* I can tell about the movie.. does anyone know it??

Comment: I should require ALL identify-this-* questions to be in this format :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**I found it !**

The movie is titled ["Crazy for a kiss"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112733/); a tv movie for which I have not seen a cover even no wonder how hard it was to find.

The title doesn't help either as it is not romantic

How did I find it? - I knew the actor was in movies of the kind i pointed so I regularly went to IMDB and watch pictures of any teenager that looked similar to the main actor.. and a few days ago I found shaun weiss. - his big change of look didnt help either :D

Sadly, I don't seem to find any way of getting a copy of this movie

Comment: According to the Wikipedia entry for Mike McShane: "the film has never been released on video or DVD." You might be interested in this [clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEoc92bXgMs) of it. Director Chris Bould says he has a copy...

Comment: Thats awesome! Hats off to your try!

Answer (score 0):

This is [Manic](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0252684/) Starring Joseph Gordon-Levitt. Here is a [link](http://movieclips.com/ZVz8e-manic-movie-videos/) to a full rundown of the movie.

It was shown at Sundance and was also the first pairing of him and Actress Zooey Deschanel.

There are a few differences in your description and the movie: the main character is not fat, the parents don't come to pick him up at least not at the end. But I think this is the one you watched.

Comment: it cant be this as he says he watched it 18 years ago and manic was made in 2001

Comment: Thank you kevin, but this is not the movie, the one I watched is older and has a different plot. You see, the main character gets out of the institution, he never harms anyone

Comment: @jampez77 People are often wrong on the year they watched an unknown movie. 11 years ago might seem like 18 to a persons memory. A lot of that movies description matches the description given and since it's an identify question usually only the asker can know for sure if it's the correct movie or not.

Comment: @quinestor Sorry this one didn't match yours. The main character does get out of the institution buts decides to go back. I wasn't clear on the first reading who stabbed the bully. Hope you find your movie.

Answer (score -3):

Your description matches a bit with this movie-

[One Flew Over the Cuckoo's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Flew_Over_the_Cuckoo%27s_Nest_%28film%29).

Also you would like to have a look at these **[movies](http://www.bridges4kids.org/articles/2003/1-03/iCAN1-03.html)**. It lists movies whose stars are suffering from disabilities.

Comment: Apart from the words "mental asylum", I don't think it sounds anything like One Flew Over the Cuckoos Nest

Comment: Hello Sahil,  appreciate you're trying to help. Sadly that's not the movie.  I checked the list you posted, didn't find it but sure there are interesting films there to watch